# mouse over text on ng-disable input as textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two text box like this, as soon as you enter some text in textbox1, textbox2 will be disabled, which is working. Second requirement is, upon disable, on hover over the second text, it should display "You can enter only in one textbox".

Can someone please help me on this..,

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, you must put a ng-disabled with the conditional for the firs requirement and the input title with a angularjs expression:

html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="validateController as vm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.first" >
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.second" 
    ng-disabled="!!vm.first" title="{{vm.first ? 'You can enter only in one textbox': ''}}">
 </div> 
</div>
```

js

```
(function(){
 angular.module('myApp',[]);
})();

(function(){ 
  angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('validateController',validateController);

  function validateController(){
   var vm = this;    
  }
})();
```

this is the codepen [solution](https://codepen.io/gabrielxm/pen/MBeoZd?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

Here is code:

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="firstbox" onmouseleave="disablesecond(3)" onmouseover="disablesecond(2)">
<input type="text" id="second"  onmouseleave="disablesecond(3)" onmouseover="disablesecond(1)">
<p id="info"></p>
<script>
   function disablesecond(needtoblock){
        if(needtoblock == 1){
         document.getElementById("firstbox").disabled = true;
         document.getElementById("second").disabled = false;
         document.getElementById("info").innerHTML= "Only one box!";
        }else if(needtoblock == 2){
         document.getElementById("second").disabled = true;
         document.getElementById("firstbox").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("info").innerHTML= "Only one box!";
        }else{
         document.getElementById("firstbox").disabled = false;
         document.getElementById("second").disabled = false;
         document.getElementById("info").innerHTML= "";
        }
   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any chance, that you can do me the favor of doing the same with ng-if condition if possible please..... I really appreciate your time though...

Comment: @Krishna You can just change it for your code, the idea is given.